# Apache Server executes console command faster than terminal

Tags: python, linux, apache, cgi

I am running my python script using CGI and Apache Server. The script runs a console command (grep) using subprocess module. The same command when run on console takes about 10 seconds to run.

```
Command: subprocess.check_output('grep %s %s'%
                 (pattern,Destination),shell=True)
```

This command on Apache takes 1-2 seconds

Whereas, `grep pattern destination` takes 10 seconds on console

What is the reason for this? I was hoping the terminal command to be faster. What happens when a script executes a console command using Apache that makes this difference?

Comment: How many lines of output does that command generate? Roughly speaking, that is. Is it closer to ten or ten thousand?

Comment: @duskwuff     this grep command returns 10 lines.